# Diferences between ESP8266_RTOS_SDK and esp-open-sdk

Tags: c++, esp8266

I've compile and flashed both examples from ESP8266_RTOS_SDK (using gen_misc.sh) and esp-open-sdk both I noticed uses different libraries. esp-open-sdk seems to point to nonOS libraries but works with RTOS as well?! There's the blink project template that I've tried to include the uart library `#include "uart.h"` but it doesn't find it so I've tried to copy and paste it on the project (I don't think that's the right way) but it can't find the function `UART_SetBaudrate`, how should I properly add the uart lib? Should I compile with `gen_misc.sh` from `ESP8266_RTOS_SDK` or using the `makefile` from `esp-open-sdk` in the blink project?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you do not have compiled liberary such *.a so you first need to 
add driver in make file as well as source code of driver then run ./gen_mish.sh
file 
as you can follow below steps 
Generate libdriver.a in SDK/lib, in driver_lib folder, run:

```
./make_lib.sh driver
```